# jQuery: Get value of object created after page load

Tags: jquery

I'm sorry for my English! :-) I need your help.

I have a php+jquery page, In this page I have a dynamic table in which you can add or remove rows with function *appendTo*. I need the selected value in the select inside the created row.

How can I get it?

This is jquery code:

```
$("#ss_serviceRequiredAdd").click(function () {

     newRow++;

     var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'srTableRow' + newRow);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<td><select class="textbox" id="servicesSR'+newRow+'" name="servicesSR[]" class="textbox"/></select></td><td><input type="text" id="ss_srProtocol" name="ss_srProtocol[]" class="textbox"/></td><td><input type="text" id="ss_srPort" name="ss_srPort[]" class="textbox"/></td><td><input type="text" id="ss_srDescription" name="ss_srDescription[]" class="textbox"/></td><td align="center"><input title="Delete" id="ss_serviceRequiredRemove" class="deleteSSP" value="'+newRow+'"/></td>');

     newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#srTable");

     var selectOpt = "#servicesSR" + newRow;

     $(selectOpt).load("../../config/select/services.php"); 
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: add your html and see live and on jquery

Comment: what you have got by `$(".textbox").val();` ?

Comment: For the textbox created after page load null value